# CGridView show data from dataProvider

Tags: arrays, yii, dataprovider, cgridview

I have a data provider which generates content like:

```
array(
    [0] => ParentObjects array(
         Child1Object array(...),
         Child2Object array(...),
    )
)
```

The first level of this array will always be 1.
I want to show in a CGridView the content of both childs.

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Campanii', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'with'=>array('stocs','produse'),
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>20,
    ),
)); 
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'columns'=>array(
                    array('name'=>'Cod','value'=>'$data->stocs[0]->cod_produs'),
                ),
));
```

As you see, the column `cod` has the value `array('name'=>'Cod','value'=>'$data->stocs[1]->cod_produs')`. Notice that [0]. Instead of that zero, I want something like an iterator. In this case, it shows me the content of that attributes in a column.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write any complex expression you want. However, for readability it is better to use an actual function. This example assumes PHP 5.3+, if your environment doesn't support that, just create a normal function instead of an anonymous one (or find a better environment).

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'columns' => array(
    array(
      'name' => 'Cod',

      // needed when returning HTML instead of plain text
      'type' => 'raw',

      // this function is called each time a cell needs to be rendered
      'value' => function(Companii $data) {
        $codes = array();
        foreach($data->stocs as $stoc) {
          $code = CHtml::encode($stoc->cod_produs);
          $codes []= CHtml::tag('li', array(), $code);
        }

        $codes = implode("\n", $codes);
        return CHtml::tag('ul', array(), $codes);
      },
    ),
  ),
));
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted. I want to show the content of `$data->stocs` on each row of the table, not inside a cell.

Comment: Can you reformulate that with an example?

Comment: I don't want all my `$data->stocs[0]->cod_produs` inside a cell. I want to show them on a separate row of the table. I am trying to show two models (`stocs`,`produse`) which are held in another model `Campanii`. Shortly, my table must show the content of `stocs` and `produse` from `Campanii` "container"

Comment: I do not believe what you want (different row types) is doable through CGridView, sorry.

Comment: My alternative was to create a `CModelForm`, put the data from `stocs` and `produse` into an array of `CModelForm`, created a `CArrayDataProvider` and passed it to `CGridView.